# Why can not trigger ADC with timer1 CC1 event?

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, stm32f4

I am working on stm32f407. What I want to do is to trigger ADC1 and ADC2 with timer1 CC1 event, but it not work. I have tried to trigger ADC1 and ADC2 with timer3 trgo or cc1 event, it works fine. So I don't know why timer1 cc1 event not work, could anyone help me？ Thanks, following is my code.

```
int main(void) 
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    ADC_InitTypeDef  ADC_InitStructure;

    NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_2);    

    /* Config GPIO */
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_4;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* Config ADC1 */

    /* ADC1 clock and reset*/
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphResetCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphResetCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1,DISABLE);

    /* ADC1 config */
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 2;
    /* config trigger event */
    // ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T3_CC1;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;

    ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);

    /* ADC1 channel config */
    /* channel 4 for PA4 */
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_4, 1, ADC_SampleTime_480Cycles);
    /* channel 5 for PA5 */
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_5, 2, ADC_SampleTime_480Cycles);

    /* ADC Common config */
    ADC_CommonInitTypeDef  ADC_CommonInitStructure;
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent; 
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TwoSamplingDelay_5Cycles;
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_Disabled;
    ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div4;
    ADC_CommonInit(&ADC_CommonInitStructure);

    /* Enable ADC1 */
    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

    /* Configure TIMER1 */
    TIM1_Int_Init(5000-1,8400-1);

    while (1) {} 
}
void TIM1_Int_Init(u16 arr,u16 psc) 
{
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef       TIM_OCInitStructure;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM1,ENABLE);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = arr;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler=psc;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode=TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision=TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM1,&TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0xFF;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_Low; 
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM1, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM1, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM1, ENABLE);

    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM1, ENABLE);       
    TIM_Cmd(TIM1, ENABLE); 
}
```

What makes me more confused is that if I enable TIM1_CC_IRQn interrupt, I can really capture the CC1 interupt in TIM1_CC_IRQHandler.

Does anyone have some ideas about this ?

---

Most resent status is I found that if I enable the CC1 interrupt then the CC1 event can triger ADC1, and now my problem is why I have to enable CC1 interrupt ? Does it matters whether I enalbe CC1 interrupt or not ? 
And I really do not need to enable CC1 interrupt if I trigger ADC1 with timer3's CC1 event.

Comment: Yes It does matter. You need to enable the interrupt!

Comment: Thanks SamR, but why I do not need to enable interrupt if I use timer3 instead?

Answer (score 0):

make sure bit MOE in register TIMx_BDTR is set